# Android transfer View over the internet and redisplaying it

Tags: android, serialization

It is possible to transfer a View, such as a TextView over the internet to say, another phone running android, and have that phone redisplay what was in the original TextView? If so, how can it be done? Does serialization work on View objects?

Comment: Why not just send the text and rebuild the TextView from that on the other side?

Comment: Because you can't really do that with other things such as buttons, unless you specifically write code for every type of widget/view

Comment: Why not? Simply pass some data indicating what type of view it is, and inflate it based on that, then insert the proper data. What's your end goal?

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to transfer a View, such as a TextView over the internet to say, another phone running android, and have that phone redisplay what was in the original TextView?

Only if you write the code for that yourself.

> Because you can't really do that with other things such as buttons, unless you specifically write code for every type of widget/view

Correct.

Now, if you are willing to send an *image* of the widget over to the other party, that you should be able to do on a general basis, having the widget draw itself to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`. You would then convert the `Bitmap` to a PNG or JPEG and send that over the Internet to the other party.